# Исполнение JS-кода из расширения для chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Недавно начал писать расширения для *chrome*. Мне нужно, чтобы, например, при нажатии в расширении на кнопку, на внешней странице исполнялся JS код.

Как это возможно сделать?

Comment: что значит внешняя страница?

Comment: то, что не в самом расширении